# Firestore Pagination : how to set Cursor for startAt using Rest Api

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I'm using firebase firestore using Rest API to get data limited by 5 documents only, ordered by a field called `LikesCount`.
When I want to fetch the next 5 documents I have to use `startAt` and pass the `LikesCount` value of the last document from the first 5 documents.
But in this way, it will fetch wrong data when there is another document with the same `LikesCount` value So I tried and searched a lot about how to pass the last Document id in addition to the `LikesCount` value But all of them did not work In addition, I tested the pagination using the Web SDK and it was working correctly because you can pass the document snapshot easily, **but what does the document snapshot object include?** So that we can understand the structure of the `Cursor` and apply it to the REST API.

**I tried to use this method to pass the Document ID as referenceValue**

```
{
    "structuredQuery": {
        "from": [{
            "collectionId": "Users"
        }],
        "where": {
            "compositeFilter": {
                "op": "AND",
                "filters": []
            }
        },
        "orderBy": [{
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "LikesCount"
            },
            "direction": "DESCENDING"
        }],
      "startAt":
      { "values": [
        {
          "integerValue": "6"
        },
        {
          "referenceValue": "projects/myprojectid/databases/(default)/documents/Posts/xEvmJ1LLHwTKVREQfXtX"
        }
      ],
     "before": false
      },
      "limit":5
    }
}
```

But an error will occur : **Cursor has too many values.**

also, I tried to pass only the `referenceValue` and it still did not return the correct 5 documents.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

Your `orderBy()` has 1 field (`LikesCount`) but your `startAt()` has 2 fields.  I suspect that is the reason for the error message?

Passing the `integerValue` won't work.  If there are 13 results with the value `6`, then each time you make the above call you'd get the same first 5 results.

When you say:

> I tried only passing the `referenceValue` and still did not get the correct 5 documents

what documents are you getting?  What documents were you expecting to get?

Comment: I thought it would help to prevent skipping documents with the same LikesCount value ,and This is my question: How can I prevent documents from being skipped even if there are other documents with the same value Or what should I put in startAt to prevent this

Comment: I tried to put integerValue only in startAt and it was working fine but when there are documents with the same value it will skip it

Comment: You provided the reference of the last document fetched from the previous fetch, which basically says "of the (ordered!) result set, start with THIS DOCUMENT REFERENCE and get me 5 documents"  (where 5 is your limit).

If there are 13 results with the same value, you'd get the first 5 and keep the reference of the 5th document, so that when you call the query again, you'd pass that 5th reference ("get me 5 more, starting from this 5th document").

Now, you might want to use `startAfter()` rather than `startAt()`.  But get it working first.

Comment: Looks like `startAfter()` is not documented in the REST API for Firestore.  So maybe this isn't available yet?

You likely need to deal with the off-by-one using `startAt()` to get your last document a second time, then simply skip over it.  If you fetch a `limit(6)` fetching your last document with `startAt()`, then you'll get 5 new documents each fetch to display to the user.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will try to solve this problem or use the c# library